# Does armour weight half as much when you wear it?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, armor, encumbrance

My GM told me that if you wear armour it weighs half as much as if you carry it. Is this part of the official Pathfinder rules, or is it a houserule?

Comment: It might make more sense if you use the term "encumbrance" instead of "weight". A suit of armour is more encumbering stuffed in a sack or backpack than it is draped correctly around the body, where shoulders and hips can share the weight. As posted below, I'm vaguely sure this was an AD&D 1st ed rule (but not sure enough to post as an answer).

Answer (score 11):

The only figure I can find for half weight in the [pathfinder source reference document](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor#TOC-Weight) is about armor fit for small creatures (which is smaller to start with and thus weights half as much as a medium-sized one).

No official rule exists to my knowledge about halving weight by donning armor (and I'd be surprised if it existed).
As SevenSidedDie points out, that rule used to exist on AD&D, and I suspect D&D 3.x got rid of it when they introduced load equivalents for wearing medium and heavy armor. Wearing armor is still more cumbersome than just having it in the backpack, but not because of weight variations.

(On a side note, it looks like D&D 3.x smiths are unable to craft decent-fitting armors. Since they weight the same and they're better balanced when worn, they must limit your movements because they are bulky and uncomfortable to wear.)

Comment: As a (now-deleted) guessing-answer noted, this is a rule in AD&D.  My guess is that the GM has carried it forward as a house rule, possibly without remembering that it is a house rule.

Comment: Worth noting: that armor for small creatures doesn't suddenly start weighing half as much when a small creature puts it on. The armor itself is _already_ small and weighs half as much as a result.

Comment: @Zachiel "Wearing armor is still more cumbersome..."? From experience, I'd much rather wear 20kg of armor than carrying 20kg of armor, since a decent-fitting armor is easier to move around while wearing than it is when it's in a bag you are carrying. That doesn't change the rules-as-written, though.

Comment: @Vatine I'm talking about the rules. In the game, it's easier to carry a complete armor than to swim or run in it.

Comment: My understanding of the RAW: Human (30ft move) with 17 STR (86lb light), unarmoured, walking carrying a 50lb set of full plate has a Walk move of 30ft. Same human wearing the same armour has a Walk move of 20ft. You're right, it is easier to carry it than wear it. Strange.

Comment: It makes sense if you consider that placement or volume or such aren't taken into consideration, just the weight. So sorta magically in this universe weight seems to be distributed effectively anyways. However if you wear the armor you don't just have the weight you also have the friction/resistance that it puts up to your moving in it. Swimming in plate is hard, but if you're carrying the weight in a masterwork backpack that doesn't seem to have water resistance or such, having your legs free might help swimming hard enough not to sink? Not saying it's realistic, but it is raw.

Comment: Remember that where it actually matters that you wear armor - in combat - you don't "walk", you "[hustle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/exploration-movement#TOC-Movement)". Maybe a long walk in a full plate is easier than carrying it in a backpack, but for short, sudden moves with frequent changes of direction it is different.

Answer (score 1):

The only logical answer I can conceive is that an armor's *effective* weight is reduced due to being worn over a large area of the body and thus spread out fairly evenly and thus for the purposes of encumbrance would be treated as half weight compared to holding it in a large bag slung over one shoulder.